# Синтаксис в строках

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cmd

Есть команда для cmd (запуск процесса от имени системы), записать данный код для аргумента ProcessStartInfo в виде строки, не получается, есть возможность конвертировать строку (с отсутствием проверки синтаксиса) во что либо с последующей возможностью использование как строку в нужный момент.

> Пример для CMD

```
cmd /c sc create -- binPath= "cmd /c start  \"\"  \"C:\Windows\regedit.exe\" " type= own type= interact & net start -- & sc delete --
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для того что бы компилятор не обращал внимание на содержимое строки, можно воспользоваться следующим синтаксисом:

```
string path = @"c:\windows\system32\";
```

Экранирование слэшей в данном случае не требуется. Но и вставить, например, перенос строки `\n` тоже не получится, вернее он не будет обрабатываться как управляющий символ.

С двойными кавычками все хуже. Т.к. они являются частью синтаксиса языка и требуют обязательного экранирования `\"`, что не сочетается с `@`. В этом случае их можно вставить используя символьную константу в виде кода `'\u0022'`, либо экранировать кавычки удвоением:

```
string cmd = @"notepad.exe ""c:\My docs\draft.txt"" ";
```

С рекомендациями и примерами Microsoft по поводу двойных кавычек можно ознакомиться **[тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/267k4fw5(v=vs.110).aspx)** (по данной ссылке не указан вариант с экранированием кавычек путем удвоения)

Comment: кавычки экранируются кавычками, то есть их надо просто удвоить

Comment: спасибо не знал, правда работает с "собакой"... сейчас поправлю

Comment: textBox1.Text = @"She said, ""You deserve a treat!"" ";

Comment: @Mirdin да уж, проглядел однако